# How do I properly import a csv file for a 52 playing card deck?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, read.csv

I am working on a project to create the war card game in python. The assignment calls for the 52 playing card deck to be created with a csv file but I am having trouble with it. I created the csv file through excel and tried to import it but its not working. I am a beginner.

Heres the excel csv file :
![2]:https://gyazo.com/60b87342bbe22b8feffb1b2d8a5653ae

I tried to follow the professors example but it doesn't really work for this assignment.

```
   import csv
    with open('PlayingCards.csv')as csvfile:
    PlayingCards = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter = ',')
    print('Card Names','\t', 'Card Values','\t', 'Suits')

    for row in PlayingCards:
    print('%-7s %-10s% 3.2f% 3.2f'%
        (row[0],row[1]))
```

I expect it to print out like this or something similar:![1]: https://gyazo.com/d2fc57640c3b64640c1ebde652b4d808
But I get an error.

Comment: can you also add an example content of your PlayingCards.csv file?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Okay I added it.

Comment: use pandas and load the csv, should give you as a dataframe, then you can manipulate it as you want, to get the columns you like. Use this reference to learn : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Comment: @Kenstars I don't think I would be able to use pandas because I was not taught about it in class and I can only use the material we learned.

Comment: @Megan, then Let me give it as a full-fledged answer so it is easier to learn for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this particular work, you need to understand what type of data you are dealing with.
The suits are like the master deck they go with every value of card.

so the first phase of this is going to be like this.

```
import csv
card_name_to_value_dict = {}
suit_list = []
with open('PlayingCards.csv')as csvfile:
     PlayingCards = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
     for row in PlayingCards
         new_cardname, new_cardvalue, new_suitvalue = row
         if new_cardname:
            card_name_to_value_dict[new_cardname] = new_cardvalue
         if new_suitvalue.strip():
            suit_list.append(new_suitvalue.replace("\n",""))
string_result = "\n".join(["\t".join([name, suit, value]) for each_suit in suit_list for name,value in card_name_to_value_dict.items()])      
print string_result
# The string result can be saved into a file for submission
```

I've reused most of the variables where possible so that you can understand it easier, let me know if you need any clarification.